# Object ID assignment in Python (for lists)

Tags: python-3.x, list

I recently discovered this interesting behavior of Python when it doesn't generate unique object IDs after instantiating a couple of new list objects.

Let me demonstrate:

```
print('id([1, 2, 3])= ', id([1, 2, 3]))
a = [1, 2, 3]
print('a= ', a)
print('id(a)= ', id(a))
print('id([1, 2, 3])= ', id([1, 2, 3]))
print('id(a)= ', id(a))
```

The output in terminal:

```
id([1, 2, 3])=  140117092252416
a=  [1, 2, 3]
id(a)=  140117092252416
id([1, 2, 3])=  140117090393920
id(a)=  140117092252416
```

Despite calling [1,2,3] multiple times, there are two unique object IDs available.I got confused. Shouldn't they be the same in my mind?

Comment: i think when you call `id([1,2,3])` multiple times, you're creating a new list object `[1,2,3]` each time and hence, the id accordingly changes. to avoid this, we use a variable and assign the list object to said variable, ensuring the id remains the same throughout the variable's lifetime.

Answer (score 0):

Why should these object have the same IDs? They are **different instances**, that just happen to have the same content. String and numeric literals have the same ID, but that's an optimization that's only allowed since they're immutable.

If the two lists would have the same ID, it would mean they'd be the same instance of a list. That would also mean that you could change `a` by doing this:

```py
a = [1, 2, 3]
[1, 2, 3].append(4)
```